# Does NltkNet the NLTK wrapper class support .NET core web applications or only console applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I try to Initialize the NltkNet object in my dotnet core web application I receive an error saying an assembly is not found or has a different manifest definition than its assembly reference.

[image]

The code is fairly simple, it does nothing at all except initialize an NltkNet object when a button is clicked.

```
public IActionResult Upload()
{
    Nltk.Init(new List<string>()
    {
        @"C:\IronPython27\Lib",
        @"C:\IronPython27\Lib\site-packages",
    });


            return View();
        }
```

I was able to get the exact same code to work in my console application without issue.

Is this a configuration issue on my end or is ASP.NET core MVC web application support not available for NltkNet?

Comment: As mentioned in this article: https://github.com/nrcpp/NltkNet, NltkNet
supported Frameworks are .net 4.5 or later, so NltkNet should not be supported in core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that NltkNet does not support dotnet core.

Comment: did you find any alternative? I am also looking for using NLTK in my .net application.

Comment: @CSS I ended up just doing my own implementations of common NLTK algorithms that I needed, as I could not find a reasonable way to support dotnet core.